# Existence of an affine variety with homotopy type of suspension of another affine variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homotopy-theory, morse-theory, hodge-structure, mixed-hodge-structure

Let $X$ be an affine variety. My question is does there exist another affine variety with the homotopy type of the suspension of $X$?

Comment: It would be very helpful to know given an affine variety$X$ does there exists another affine variety $Y$ such that $H_{i+1}(Y)=H_{i}(X)$?